# Where to put PowerShell Modules in a 64-bit environment

Tags: powershell

I have made my first PowerShell module. I wonder where to put it. First of all, it seems that I have to put them in both a 32-bit and a 64-bit location, for example:

- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

or

- C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
- C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

I don't like this. I don't want to copy my files twice when I have a new version.

I there some best practice for where to put the modules? Like in a folder that can be used for both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Comment: "it seems that I have to" - from what? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Comment: When I run PowerShell ISE, it loads the 32-bit modules. When I run this using our CI environment, it uses the 64-bit modules. So it looks to me that sometimes it will use the 32-bit folder, and sometimes the 64-bit folder. My code is independent on the architecture, so I'd rather have them in the same folder for both.

Comment: @Roel Check the `$env:PSModulePath` variable, both the 64-bit and 32-bit executables reference the same locations

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx